# replace a tag inside a string variabile using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to dinamically change the content of a textarea initialized with tinymce editor, based on external input field. For example:

I have a input text like this:

```
<input type="text" id="descr" value="This is a demo">
```

And a textarea inizialized with tinymce plugin:

```
<textarea id="content">Hi this is a text and this is a dynamic field: <span data-placeholder="mydescr">This is a demo</span> .<br>If you change text input, then new value is reported above!</textarea>
```

Now i'd like to change text inside textarea IF I change input field #descr.

```
$("#descr").on("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newValue = $(this).val();
  var content = $("#content").val();
  var replacedValue = $(content).find("[data-placeholder]").text(newValue);

  //...i don't know how to glue it again

});
```

At this point, if i write "BLA BLA BLA" inside input text field, the editor need to change automatically into:

```
<textarea id="content">Hi this is a text and this is a dynamic field: <span data-placeholder="mydescr">BLA BLA BLA</span> .<br>If you change text input, then new value is reported above!</textarea>
```

But I not sure how to re-glue the unchanged text, with changed text. Any suggest?

Comment: How to "re-glue"?
What do you need to achieve?

I think you just need to inizialize tinymcs after you changed the value.
If i was able to get the point of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because the content inside `textarea` is considered plain text, I believe you cannot select it like a DOM element. You'd need to use regex to select the text between those html tags.
Here's one way to do it:

```js
$("#descr").on("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newValue = $(this).val();
  var content = $("#content").val();
  $("#content").val(content.replace(/(?<=<span data-placeholder="mydescr">)(.*)(?=<\/span>)/, newValue));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="descr" value="This is a demo">
<textarea id="content">Hi this is a text and this is a dynamic field: <span data-placeholder="mydescr">This is a demo</span> .<br>If you change text input, then new value is reported above!</textarea>
```